# Emberjs - simple app not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm just going through the Emberjs tutorial on http://trek.github.com/, but parts of the code is not returning the expected output.

My HTML is

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0-rc.3/handlebars.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/emberjs/ember.js/release-builds/ember-1.0.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/App.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
        <h1>Ember committers</h1>
        {{outlet}}
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="contributors">
        {{#each person in controller}}
            {{person.login}}
        {{/each}}
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

My App.js (written in App.coffee)

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create()

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend
    templateName:"application"

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend()

App.AllContributorsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend()
App.AllControbutorsView = Ember.View.extend
    templateName:"contributors"

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend
    root:Ember.Route.extend
        index:Ember.Route.extend
            route:"/"
            connectOutlets: (router) ->
                router.get("applicationController").connectOutlet("allContributors", [{login:'wycats'},{login:'tomdale'}])
```

I expect the "wycats" and "tomdale" to be printed out, but there's nothing. Here's my jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Djunu/

Comment: I found the full code of the tutorial on jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/ZKXyg/, but looks like that example isn't working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is based on an outdated API. Ember 1.0.rc has a completely new and much friendler way of defining routes and setting up controllers. Refer to this guide for up-to-date material: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/